# Having all my predictions inclined to one side for binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I was training a model that contains 8 features that allow us to predict the probability of a room been sold.

- Region: The region the room belongs to (an integer, taking a value between 1 and 10)
- Date: The date of stay (an integer between 1‐365, here we consider only one‐day request)
- Weekday: Day of week (an integer between 1‐7)
- Apartment: Whether the room is a whole apartment (1) or just a room (0)
- #beds:The number of beds in the room (an integer between 1‐4)
- Review: Average review of the seller (a continuous variable between 1 and 5)
- Pic Quality: Quality of the picture of the room (a continuous variable between 0 and 1)
- Price: he historic posted price of the room (a continuous variable)
- Accept: Whether this post gets accepted (someone took it, 1) or not (0) in the end*

Column Accept is the "y". Hence, this is a binary classification.

---

1. I have done `OneHotEncoder` for the categorical data.
2. I have applied normalization to the data.
3. I have modified the following `RandomRofrest` parameters:

- `Max_depth`: Peak at 16
- `n_estimators`: Peak at 300
- `min_samples_leaf`:
  Peak at 2
- `max_features`: Has no effect on the AUC.

The AUC peaked at 0.7889. What else can I do to increase it?

---

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df_train = pd.read_csv('case2_training.csv')

# Exclude ID since it is not a feature
X, y = df_train.iloc[:, 1:-1], df_train.iloc[:, -1]
y = y.astype(np.float32)

# Split the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.05,shuffle=False)

ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse = False)
column_trans = make_column_transformer(
(OneHotEncoder(),['Region','Weekday','Apartment']),remainder='passthrough')
X_train = column_trans.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = column_trans.fit_transform(X_test)

# Normalization
from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler
mabsc = MaxAbsScaler()

X_train = mabsc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = mabsc.transform(X_test)

X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32)
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

RF =  RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_leaf=2,random_state=0, n_estimators=300,max_depth = 16,n_jobs=-1,oob_score=True,max_features=i)
cross_val_score(RF,X_train,y_train,cv=5,scoring = 'roc_auc').mean()
RF.fit(X_train, y_train)
yhat = RF.predict_proba(X_test)

print("AUC:",roc_auc_score(y_test, yhat[:,-1]))

# Run the prediction on the given test set.
testset = pd.read_csv('case2_testing.csv')
testset = testset.iloc[:, 1:] # exclude the 'ID' column
testset = column_trans.fit_transform(testset)
testset = mabsc.transform(testset)


yhat_2 = RF.predict_proba(testset)
final_prediction = yhat[:,-1]
```

However, all the probabilities from 'final_prediction` are below 0.45, basically, the model believes that all the samples are 0.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: In your last line, do you mean `yhat_2[:,-1]`?

Comment: @StevenRouk Predict_proba will gives the probabilities of two classes which in this case is 0 and 1. My target is to find the possibility of 1 so i selected the second column.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `column_trans.fit_transform` on the test set, this completely overwrites the features that were fitted during training. Basically the data is now in a format your trained model doesn't understand.

Once fitted in training on the training set, simply use `column_trans.transform` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for answering but it did not solve the problem.  `testset = column_trans.transform(testset)` did not make any change to the results, all the answers were still inclined to '0'

Comment: Note that you are doing that twice in your code, not only on `testset`. Also you should write `testset = testset.iloc[:,1:1]` to exclude the last column. After that you are using `fit_transform` and then `transform` again? what does that even mean?

Comment: 1. The exclusively loaded `testset` does not have the last column so I did not need to manipulate that part. 2. My intuition behind the `fit_transform` for the `testset` was to OneHotEncoder the features since the model was trained based on OneHotEncoder feastures. It followed by `mabsc.transform(testset)` which was to normalization the input values. 3. Please notice that `X_test` was part of 1st CSV file and `testset` was from another CSV file.