# Extremely high loss with consistent validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

This is a question from Coursera. Everything output as expected expect for the training part.
I have tried different layers but they were the same. Maybe some mistakes in my manipulation of the dataset?

I couldn't found it ,can somebody help?
Thanks

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from os import getcwd

def get_data(filename):
  # You will need to write code that will read the file passed
  # into this function. The first line contains the column headers
  # so you should ignore it
  # Each successive line contians 785 comma separated values between 0 and 255
  # The first value is the label
  # The rest are the pixel values for that picture
  # The function will return 2 np.array types. One with all the labels
  # One with all the images
  #
  # Tips: 
  # If you read a full line (as 'row') then row[0] has the label
  # and row[1:785] has the 784 pixel values
  # Take a look at np.array_split to turn the 784 pixels into 28x28
  # You are reading in strings, but need the values to be floats
  # Check out np.array().astype for a conversion
    with open(filename) as training_file:
        
      # Your code starts here
      reader = csv.reader(training_file)
      next(reader,None)
      images = []
      labels = []
      for i in reader:
            
            labels.append(i[0])
            imageData = i[1:785]
            images.append(np.array_split(imageData,28))
            
      # Your code ends here
      labels = np.array(labels).astype('float')
      images = np.array(images).astype('float')
    return images, labels

path_sign_mnist_train = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/sign_mnist_train.csv"
path_sign_mnist_test = f"{getcwd()}/../tmp2/sign_mnist_test.csv"
training_images, training_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_train)
testing_images, testing_labels = get_data(path_sign_mnist_test)

# Keep these
print(training_images.shape)
print(training_labels.shape)
print(testing_images.shape)
print(testing_labels.shape)

# In this section you will have to add another dimension to the data
# So, for example, if your array is (10000, 28, 28)
# You will need to make it (10000, 28, 28, 1)

training_images = np.expand_dims(training_images,axis=-1)# Your Code Here
testing_images = np.expand_dims(testing_images,axis=-1)# Your Code Here

# Create an ImageDataGenerator and do Image Augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.,
                                   rotation_range = 40,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   fill_mode = 'nearest'
    )

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255.)
    
# Keep These
print(training_images.shape)
print(testing_images.shape)
    
# Their output should be:
# (27455, 28, 28, 1)
# (7172, 28, 28, 1)

# Define the model
# Use no more than 2 Conv2D and 2 MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')])


# Compile Model. 
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Train the Model
train_generator = train_datagen.flow(training_images,training_labels,
                                                    batch_size = 10
                                                     
                                                  )  
validation_generator =  validation_datagen.flow( testing_images,
                                                
                                                testing_labels,
                                                batch_size  = 10  
                                                         )
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              epochs=5,
                              steps_per_epoch=len(training_images) / 32,
                              validation_data=validation_generator
                              
                             )

model.evaluate(testing_images, testing_labels,verbose=0)
```

The output of the model is shown as below :

```
Epoch 1/5
858/857 [==============================] - 78s 91ms/step - loss: 15.4250 - accuracy: 0.0422 - val_loss: 15.5210 - val_accuracy: 0.0371
Epoch 2/5
858/857 [==============================] - 75s 88ms/step - loss: 15.4719 - accuracy: 0.0401 - val_loss: 15.5210 - val_accuracy: 0.0371
Epoch 3/5
858/857 [==============================] - 77s 89ms/step - loss: 15.4230 - accuracy: 0.0431 - val_loss: 15.5210 - val_accuracy: 0.0371
Epoch 4/5
858/857 [==============================] - 76s 89ms/step - loss: 15.4268 - accuracy: 0.0429 - val_loss: 15.5120 - val_accuracy: 0.0371
Epoch 5/5
858/857 [==============================] - 75s 88ms/step - loss: 15.4287 - accuracy: 0.0428 - val_loss: 15.5120 - val_accuracy: 0.0371
```

The batch size is low because the Jupyter notebook from Coursera has it limited to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct.  I suspect it has something to do with the optimizer.
Try using Adam instead of RMSProp and try setting the learning rate for Adam to 0.001 which is the default learning rate.  Other than that, your notebook is correctly extracting out the labels and data, formulating the data generators and the network appears correct.

Comment: Thank you ! That works. May i know why the optimizers affect the results so significantly? How should we choose the optimizers, do we trial and error?

Comment: @Leo It is honestly trial and error with neural networks :/.  If you see that the loss is varying wildly, a simple solution is to decrease the learning rate.  Failing that, try changing the optimizer.  This link may provide more details on better selection: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/10523.  BTW if you no longer need help, please considering accepting this answer to let the community know you no longer need help.  This can be done by going to the top of this answer, and clicking in the checkmark icon below the up & down voting arrows.  Welcome to our community!

Comment: Yes, thank you , I accept it. Would you mind to take a look at my another question which has been answered a lot and I still could not find the solutions. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63479080/having-all-my-predictions-inclined-to-one-side-for-binary-classification/63482923?noredirect=1#comment112286200_63482923) Thanks!